# bubble sort between two listboxes unsorted and sorted c#

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox

I have created a form that has two listboxes (unsorted and sorted) when i click on button bubble sort it appears in the unsorted listbox but now want to click another button for e.g. sort and it sorts them in the correct order in the sorted listbox and clears the unsorted listbox.

i'm new to programming so finding it very difficult to get my head around the coding. I have googled what i require but can't seem to find a definite answer.

the code i have is below:

**This adds it to my unsorted listbox:**

```
int[] myNumbers = { 5, 1, 8, 9, 15 };

lstunsorted.Items.Add(5);
lstunsorted.Items.Add(1);
lstunsorted.Items.Add(8);
lstunsorted.Items.Add(9);
lstunsorted.Items.Add(15);
```

**This is what i have under my sort button to move them across and sort:**

```
        for (int intCount = lstunsorted.SelectedItems.Count - 1; intCount >= 0; intCount--)
        {
            lstsorted.Items.Add(lstunsorted.SelectedItems[intCount]);
            lstunsorted.Items.Remove(lstunsorted.SelectedItems[intCount]);
        }

        int[] arr = { 5, 1, 8, 9, 15 };
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
        for (int J = 0; J < arr.Length; J++)
        {
        if (arr[i] > arr[J])
        {
                        temp = arr[i];

                        arr[i] = arr[J];

                        arr[J] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated and explained in an beginner format for me to understand what's going on.

Comment: Your order of execution of code seems incorrect. Can you put comments in your code so as to show what are you trying to achieve from that respective snippet? That would be helpful. Also I don't see you sorting the no.s and then filling it in sorted listbox. Instead it appears you are filling the sorted list box as it is from unsorted one and applying sorting logic altogether in a different space

Comment: You should add the items to the listbox AFTER sorting them. So when you click the Bubblo Sort button, the unsorted items are displayed in the unsorted listbox. When the Sort button is clicked, you should 1. get all items in the unsorted listbox; 2. Should sort them; 3. add them to the sorted listbox

Comment: @Codeek - This adds it to my unsorted listbox: This is just adding items to a listbox but not sure if i need int[] myNumbers = { 5, 1, 8, 9, 15 };. This is what i have under my sort button to move them across and sort: personally this is all wrong i believe as i was copying it from a video i seen.

Comment: @OguzOzgul - that's exactly what i want to do but as i am a beginner it's all new to me and i am learning. JonasH answer has shed some light on what i require but still having issues

Comment: Your sort is operating on an entirely different array.(`arr`). You need to either sort `lstsorted.Items` directly, or sort `arr`, and then populate `lssortedIiems` from `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox.Items` is an untyped collection meaning you can add any kind of value to it, string, int, whatever. This makes it rather cumbersome to work with, so the first step should be to convert it to a regular array or List.

```
var myArray =  lstunsorted.Items.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

`.Cast<int>()` casts each item in the list to an int. This will only work if the items are actually ints, but in your case it is fine (see `.OfType<T>()` otherwise). `.ToArray()` takes all the values and puts them in a new array.

You would then sort the items, and I assume this is the point of the exercise. If not, it can be done with

```
Array.Sort(myArray );
```

The last step would be to update the listBoxes.

```
lstsorted.Items.Clear();
foreach(var i in myArray )
{
    lstsorted.Items.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, Thanks for the reply. I am trying to understand what's going on from what you've suggested and I have to use lstunsorted.items.add to get the numbers to appear in the box when i click bubble sort. I have entered the code you've provided and I can get the items to appear but when i click sort everything works as it should except the sort doesn't work. Are you saying i only require the int[] mynumbers = { 5, 1, 8, 9, 15 }; without adding each one? Thanks again

Comment: The problem is probably in your sorting implementation, use Array.Sort or one of the many tutorials on how to write bubbleSort. First google hit: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Bubble-Sort-program-in-Chash

Comment: @chubbse25 I would also recommend learning how to use a debugger for your programs, this lets you inspect variables, control flow etc. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Comment: I've looked at the link you've provided and didn't know if the sorting code was required for a listbox, as the example is writing to a console. Can you add numbers from an array to a listbox without using the listbox.items.add? Sorry for the questions but C# programming is new to me.

Comment: @chubbse25 The sorting is not required by listbox. But if the numbers are removed from your unsorted listbox, and added to the sorted listbox, but are not sorted, then the problem is probably in the sorting code. This can easily be confirmed by using Array.Sort and see if it works.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work somehow by adding each number into the unsorted list box by using lstunsorted.Items.Add(88); for example for my bubble sort button then my sort button clears the unsorted box and sorts them in the sorted listbox using:var myArray = lstunsorted.Items.Cast<int>().ToArray();
            int[] myarray = { 88, 50, 32, 10, 16 };

            Array.Sort(myArray);

            lstunsorted.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var i in myArray)
            {
                lstsorted.Items.Add(i);
            }